# Compute the CDF of $\left[\log_2(1+X)-\log_2(1+Y)\right]^+$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X,Y$. I know their respective CDFs and PDFs. I want to find the CDF of following variable $$Z=\left[\log_2(1+X)-\log_2(1+Y)\right]^+=\left[\log_2(1+X)-\log_2(1+Y)\right]u(X-Y)$$ where $u(x)$ is the unit step function. It can be easily noted that the CCDF of $Z$ is given as below $$1-F_Z(t)=\int_0^{\infty} f_Y(y)\left[1-F_X\left(2^t(1+y)-1\right)\right]dy.$$ I want to know whether the upper limit of $Y$ in this integral is right or not? (Because $Y<X$ according to first equation) I have one explanation that the above limit ($\infty$) is right because $X>Y$ is considered by the $\left[1-F_X\left(2^t(1+y)-1\right)\right]$. Is my explanation right? If it is incorrect then please describe the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and almost surely nonnegative, this is correct, for every $t\geqslant0$. Note that, for every $t\geqslant0$, $$P(Z\leqslant t\mid Y=y)=P(X\leqslant2^t(1+y)-1)$$ hence the formula in your post.

Comment: @Did thanks for your comment and describing it the right way. I had a little   typo in my original post which I have correct (CDF of Z was written earlier instead of CCDF of Z) but it is quite interesting that your comment relate to my corrected post. Nevertheless, thanks for the help and clarifying me.

Comment: @Did do you think the answer provided by Baokai Zhang is right? I think that answer does not result in same expression as in post or in your comment. Please comment if there is something that I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Did the CDF of $Z$ from your formula will be $\int_0^{\infty} P(X\leq 2^t(1+y)-1)f_Y(y)dy$. Here again the upper limit is infinity (why it should be infinity? where does the condition $X\geq Y$ comes into play). Instead, if we try to find the CCDF of $Z$  then as Baokai Zhang mentioned in his comment (his second comment below) both the conditions on $X$ (namely $X \geq 2^t(1+Y)-1$ and $Y\leq X$) transform into one condition (that is $X \geq 2^t(1+Y)-1$) and hence the subsequent formula in his comment ....

Comment: @Did...($\int_0^{\infty} f_Y(y)\left[1-F_X(2^t(1+y)-1)\right]dy$) which is actually same as the formula in my post for the CCDF of $Z$. It looks simple by using CCDF (because both conditions can be transformed into single condition). However, when I try to understand it using CDF then I am unable to understand how does $X\leq 2^t(1+y)-1$ also take into account the fact that $X>y$. This is my problem with using CDF. I will be very thankful to you if you can explain it a bit for the CDF case also. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Did I meant Baokai Zhang's First comment (which starts with "If we assume that $Y\geq 0$ always then...") in my above comment instead of Baokai Zhang's second comment (I am extremely extremely extremely sorry for the typo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we know $Z=\Big[\log_2\frac{1+X}{1+Y}\Big]^{+}$, so $Y\leq X$. from $Z\geq 0$, we know $2^Z\geq 1$. Then
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    F_Z(t)=&P\bigg\{\log_2\frac{1+X}{1+Y}\leq t, Y\leq X\bigg\}+P\{Z=0\}\\
          =&P\big\{Y\leq X\leq 2^t(1+Y)-1\big\}+P\{X<Y\}\\              
          =&\int_{-1}^{\infty}f_Y(y)dy\int_{y}^{2^t(1+y)-1}f_X(x)dx
            +\int_{-1}^{\infty}f_Y(y)dy\int_{-1}^{y}f_X(x)dx\\
          =&\int_{-1}^{\infty}f_Y(y)F_X\big(2^t(1+y)-1\big)dy
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
the lower limit is $-1$, cause if $Y<-1$, combining with $2^t\geq 1$, will result in $2^t(1+Y)-1< Y$. The upper limit $\infty$ is natural.

Actually, $F_Z(0)=\int_{-1}^{\infty}f_Y(y)F_X(y)dy$. Also if we treat the problem from the aspect of $1-F_Z(t)$, then we need not consider the issue of $F_Z(0)$.

Comment: If we assume that $Y \geq 0$ always then your last expression is not consistent with the answer that I provided and Did mention in his comment (at least I do not get the same answer from your post, if its possible to get the same answer then please add a step or two). Thanks alot for your response.

Comment: If we assume that $Y\geq 0$ always then 
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    1-F_Z(t)=&P\bigg\{\log_2\frac{1+X}{1+Y}\geq t, Y\leq X\bigg\}\\
                 =&P\big\{X\geq 2^t(1+Y)-1\big\}\\
                 =&\int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(y)dy\int_{2^t(1+y)-1}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx\\
                 =&\int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(y)\Big[1-F_X\big(2^t(1+y)-1\big)\Big]dy
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: In fact,
$\int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(y)\Big[1-F_X\big(2^t(1+y)-1\big)\Big]dy=1-\int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(y)\Big[F_X\big(2^t(1+y)-1\big)-F_X(y)\Big]dy$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But how does $\int_0^{\infty}f_Y(y)F_X(y)dy=0$. Is it because $X>Y$ assumption? (I do not understand this part please clarify it. Thanks in advance).

Comment: It is not $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(y)F_X(y)dy=0$, you should be careful about the difference between $F_Z(t)$ and $1-F_Z(t)$.

Comment: check your second last comment ("in fact ....") which I think is only true if $\int_0^{\infty} f_Y(y)F_X(y)dy=0$. Please correct me if I am again missing something like how does the equality holds in your second last comment ("in fact ...")

Comment: I have checked my answer and comments again, I must say sorry to you.
Because I missed a crucial fact that $F_{Z}(0)>0$. I will amend my answer.

Comment: Thank you Baokai Zhang. Actually I got confused and even now I have confusion related to finding the CDF of $Z$ which I mentioned in my comments to my post (above which are directed to Did but if you can clarify the solution with the help of CDF then I will be very thankful to you.)

Comment: @Baokain Zhang how did you say that $F_Z(0)>0$. We know that $Z$ is defined only for non-negative values and further the probability of a point is zero. Combining these facts I think $F_Z(0)$ should be zero. I do not understand how you said that it is greater than zero.

Comment: $F_Z(0)=P(Z\leqslant0)=P(Y\geqslant X)\ne0$ in general.

Comment: Sorry, my write may be less rigorous. I want to add that $F_Z(0)\geq 0$ rather than $F_Z(0)>0$ due to the possible distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Did You are right.

Comment: @BaokaiZhang your answer makes a lot of sense now except I think in the fourth line you should write $\int_{-\infty}^yf_X(x)dx$ instead of $\int_{-1}^yf_X(x)dx$. Nevertheless thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your encourage. But you may forgot the reasonability of $\log_2 (1+x)$, or $Z$ can not be defined. Like Did's comment, the assumptions "$X,\ Y\in[-1,\ \infty]$ or nonnegative" and "$X,\ Y$ are mutually independent"  or other alternative assumptions may should be included in this question in advance.